# Make terminal window directly transparent to Ubuntu wallpaper

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, transparency

So before I came to Linux I was using Windows and stumbled upon a Kali version, in which when you opened a terminal and you could see through every window (Firefox) directly to your wallpaper.

Q: How can I do the same thing on Ubuntu 14.04.2?

PS. Note that I am a newbie so keep it simple!

Comment: Do you want the terminal window to be transparent and see the Firefox underneath it? If so open a terminal and look into its menu. Go **Edit > Profile Preference > Background Tab > Transparent background.**

Comment: I did that , tho i want to see the wallpaper instantly and not the window behind it =p

Comment: @Anwar: Not exactly. From what I understand, OP wants the terminal background to show the part of the desktop wallpaper right behind the terminal window (depending on the current size and location of that window).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can force the transparency to display only your wallpaper on a system running Unity.

The reason can be found in one of the `gconf` settings of `gnome-terminal` on 14.04:

```
$ gconftool-2 --long-docs /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_type

      Type of terminal background. May be "solid" for a solid color,
      "image" for an image, or "transparent" for either real transparency if
      a compositing window manager is running, or pseudo-transparency
      otherwise.
```

The only way to get a pseudo-transparency (i.e terminal background set to the wallpaper) is by running Ubuntu without a compositing manager.

If your graphics card doesn't support 3d-acceleration, Gnome 3 automatically runs the fallback-mode (which is Kali's default mode). That's why you may have seen `gnome-terminal` showing only the wallpaper.

Source:

- [make gnome-terminal real transparent](https://superuser.com/a/388329)